# Faster way to verify existing records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I want to know which of these two SQL sentences it's better in performance and best practice, in order to find an existing record? Is there another efficient way?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN
--VALIDATION
END
```

OR

```
SET @VARIABLE = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID)
IF(@VARIABLE > 0)
BEGIN
--VALIDATION
END
```

Comment: Use `IF EXISTS`. Don't force the server to count if you only care about 0 or non-0. For more efficient way, we'd probably need to know what else your query is doing - we may be able to re-write the whole lot into a single query, rather than writing procedurally.

Comment: You should try them on a big table and compare them.

Comment: The --VALIDATION part is only a bit variable to return true or false. SET @ EXIST = 1. It's a scalar-valued function

Comment: Oh, don't do this in a scalar function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If not. Why? what do I need to do? And Where?

Comment: I don't understand enough about your scenario or requirements to answer that, but stuffing this into a scalar function is only going to slow everything down.

Comment: I need to use a callback to know if a name has been already taken. Like emails for example but I have two tables where I need to find if this already exists.

Comment: So just do two `IF EXISTS ()` checks without wrapping them in a function.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I want to avoid two roundtrips to database when I can do it once. That's why I am doing my to IF Exists checks into a function

Comment: @MaximusDecimus: So just save it as a bit variable from the exists and do the one trip - no need for the two trips or a function.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus: See the example I've added to my answer re bit variable, and no function.

Comment: @JonEgerton, I'm doing something like that but less sofisticated that you did. I mean the result is at the end in a bit variable, but this is at SQL Server level. I need to call it from my web app. Do I call a SP or Function?

Comment: So you're going to save a round trip to the database (how? Isn't this code already in a stored procedure or something?) but you're going to lose any efficiency you gain due to the heinous performance of a scalar UDF? Don't try to outsmart SQL Server. Pay the cost in the round trip (or put this code in a stored procedure to solve both problems).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need to know is that there are any rows at all, the first is better - the `EXISTS` will complete once the subquery finds the first matching row.

The `COUNT(1)` must find all matching records in order to return the accurate count, which is then pretty much disregarded if all that is wanted is `>0`

In addition (IMHO) the exists statement reads much more clearly (although the second statement doesn't really need the variable).

**Update re comments**

Example of saving exists result as variable to clarify some of the comments against the question:

```
DECLARE @exists BIT
SET @exists = (CASE 
                   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID) THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
               END)

...

IF @exists = 1 
BEGIN...
```